# On the product of two deficient numbers

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to show that the product of power of 2 (which is a deficient number) and another deficient number say m is deficient. Got some results but not totally answered the main question, can somebody help me to show this? or give some hints on how to prove it in a nice manner?

Comment: Have you tested this on numbers less than $5$?

Comment: yeah, I mean deficient...

Comment: I'll type it as soon as possible, thanks... can you give a counter example to falsify the claim? Thanks

Comment: the least number to be considered is 12...

Comment: This was never specified in the question (which is in fact false for all $m$).  Please fix your question and supply the partial results you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, sure I'll show it ... when im not busy, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. $7$ is a deficient number since it is prime. And $28=2^2\cdot7$ is not deficient, but perfect. Moreover, $2^3\cdot 7=56$ is abundant.

Comment: thanks, Yeah, sorry for not specifying what is m, m is an odd non-prime.