# Product of two deficient numbers

Tags: number-theory

Is the product of two deficient numbers deficient? 
a×b=c 
Assuming that a and b are deficient and none of them is prime, is c guaranteed to be deficient?

A similar question was asked by another user 7 years ago here
[On the product of two deficient numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737869/on-the-product-of-two-deficient-numbers)
However, going by the comments, nobody really answered his question properly. If there are conditions where c is not deficient please let us list them below. I know one condition is that b must not be prime because if b is prime then c may be perfect as in the case of 4×7=28. Also list the counterexamples if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4$ is deficient, and $10$ is deficient, but $4 \times 10 = 40$ is not deficient.

Listing the counterexamples is impossible, as there is an infinite number of them.

Comment: From the question, "Assuming that a and b are deficient and none of them is prime, is c guaranteed to be deficient?" This response, unfortunately, doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit Good call. Changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will approve your answer